# Checking is WIFI is available using ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest. I need to know how to do the following events using it;

The following are the way i should be checking for the availability of the internet, but in which event should i add it to address the following issues;

```
self.remoteHostStatus           = [[Reachability sharedReachability] remoteHostStatus];
self.internetConnectionStatus   = [[Reachability sharedReachability] internetConnectionStatus];
self.localWiFiConnectionStatus  = [[Reachability sharedReachability] localWiFiConnectionStatus];
```

1.) Applications like foursquare pops out an alert **as soon as the internet is lost** ? How is this done, and in what event should i code this ? (The user might be performing a task, and suddenly the wifi goes off, then i should pop up a warning, saying no wifi available)

2.) **As soon as the internet/wifi is back** i need to refresh and update the data. How is this done? (it should be listening continuously, and once the internet is back it should update that view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a notification posted by Reachability called `kReachabilityChangedNotification`.

You can enforce the generation of that notification by using Reachability's

```
- (BOOL)startNotifier;
- (void)stopNotifier;
```

First register for that notification - for example in `viewDidLoad` of a `UIViewController`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChangedNotificationSent:) 
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

Add the following method - for example to your `UIViewController` implementation.

```
- (void)reachabilityChangedNotificationSent:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"reachability changed: %@", notification.userInfo);
}
```

Now simply invoke `startNotifier` - for example in `viewDidLoad` again and you should be informed whenever any changes happen.

```
[[Reachability sharedReachability] startNotifier];
```

Do not forget to remove yourself from that notification and to invoke `stopNotifier` when done. Sticking to my example would mean that you should add this to your `viewDidUnload` implementation.

```
[[Reachability sharedReachability] stopNotifier];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                              object:nil];
```

Comment: Can you show me how to invoke using `startNotifier ` and remove myself using 'stopNotifier ' (I am a beginner) Where should i add `[[Reachability sharedReachability] startNotifier];` ?

Comment: Ok, so i have to write all these code except for  (`reachabilityChangedNotificationSent`)within the `viewDidLoad` method ?

Comment: once again, see my edited answer. If this answer helped, please consider checking that gray checkmark to its side for accepting the answer.

Comment: i get this `no known class method for selector sharedReachability` for `[[Reachability sharedReachability] startNotifier];` line. How could i solve it ? (sorry, i am a beginner)

Comment: You actually quoted sharedReachability yourself in your question.